# How open all folders only in one buffer in dired mode?

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

When in **dired** mode when I press `Enter` over folder it's open in separate buffer. So after input in 10 folder the Emacs open 10 buffers. I know about press "`a`". But it not comfortable. I need to open folder only in ONE buffer when press `ENTER`.
How I can open all folder only in **ONE** buffer?

I don't like **dired+**. Has any another approach?

Comment: Are you asking how to make `Enter` do the same thing as `a` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to open ALL folder only in ONE buffer.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to make <kbd>RET</kbd> do what <kbd>a</kbd> does.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> in dired tells us

> `a` runs the command `dired-find-alternate-file` (found in `dired-mode-map`), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘`dired.el`’.

Therefore:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "dired"
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'dired-find-alternate-file))
```